# how to start server/client grpc using scalapb on spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, grpc, scalapb

i have a problem about running server/client using ScalaPB on spark.

its totally work fine while I running my code using "sbt run". i want running this code using spark coz next ill import my spark model to predict some label. but while I submit my jar to spark, they give me error like this.

```
   Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.ManagedChannelProvider$ProviderNotFoundException: 
No functional server found. Try adding a dependency on the grpc-netty artifact
```

this is my build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> (sourceManaged in Compile).value
)

val scalapbVersion =
    scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion
val grpcJavaVersion =
    scalapb.compiler.Version.grpcJavaVersion


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

    // protobuf
    "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapbVersion % "protobuf",

    //for grpc
    "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % grpcJavaVersion ,
    "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % scalapbVersion
)

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
       case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
       case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }
```

using shade still not work

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(ShadeRule.rename("com.google.**" -> "shadegoogle.@1").inAll)
```

and this my main

```
import java.util.logging.Logger
import io.grpc.{Server, ServerBuilder}
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import testproto.test.{Email, EmailLabel, RouteGuideGrpc}
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

object HelloWorldServer {
  private val logger = Logger.getLogger(classOf[HelloWorldServer].getName)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val server = new HelloWorldServer(ExecutionContext.global)
    server.start()
    server.blockUntilShutdown()
  }
  private val port = 50051
}

class HelloWorldServer(executionContext: ExecutionContext) {
  self =>
  private[this] var server: Server = null

  private def start(): Unit = {
    server = ServerBuilder.forPort(HelloWorldServer.port).addService(RouteGuideGrpc.bindService(new RouteGuideImpl, executionContext)).build.start
    HelloWorldServer.logger.info("Server started, listening on " + HelloWorldServer.port)
    sys.addShutdownHook {
      System.err.println("*** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down")
      self.stop()
      System.err.println("*** server shut down")
    }
  }

  private def stop(): Unit = {
    if (server != null) {
      server.shutdown()
    }
  }

  private def blockUntilShutdown(): Unit = {
    if (server != null) {
      server.awaitTermination()
    }
  }

  private class RouteGuideImpl extends RouteGuideGrpc.RouteGuide {
    override def getLabel(request: Email): Future[EmailLabel] = {
      val replay = EmailLabel(emailId = request.emailId, label = "aaaaa")
      Future.successful(replay)
    }
  }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like grpc-netty is not found when an uber jar is made. Instead of using `ServerBuilder`, change your code to use `io.grpc.netty.NettyServerBuilder`.